# Windows Azure Servicebus and Oracle Servicebus

Tags: integration, azureservicebus, oracle-service-bus

I'm working with an application which uses Windows Azure Servicebus as endpoint for in/outbound integration. A potential customer is using Oracle Servicebus as integration platform. "My" application is sending/receiving xml-based messages through topics/queues.

My thought is that it should be quite straight forward to connect these two platforms using REST or AMQP. But I have no experience with Oracle Servicebus, so I'm not ready to go all in with this thought.

Any out there who has experience with this kind of solution?

With best regards

/Anders

Comment: How do you plan to integrate? Which system will be the provider and which will be the consumer? When you talk about two platforms, you mean Azure and OSB?

Comment: Yes, "platforms" is referring to Azure and OSB. And both platforms will both act as provider and consumers in different scenarios. 

The system I'm representing is an HR/payroll-system which will provide the customers with data when employment information changes (outbound) but will also get information to persist in the HR/payroll system from customer systems (inbound) in some scenarios.

Comment: Sound to me like you already have it figured out.
Both platform fully support REST. OSB does not support AMQP but it does support Jms (and Wmq) so you may use most MQ systems. 
Choose REST/SOAP if you need a synchronous response and MQ if you do not.